# Trying to import avatar data from database, to be able output for each unique user. using vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, avatar

```
<template>
  <div id="avatarPage">

<div class="avatarBackground" style="position:relative">
    <div v-for="data in Json" :key="data.id" >
        <img :src="`https://i.ibb.co/${data.source}`"
        :id="`${data.name}`"  
            :style= 
                "`
                z-index: ${data.layer};
                position:absolute; 
                height: 500px;
                top: 0em;
                left: -5%;
                clip: rect(29px, 400px, 450px, 0);
                `"
        >
    </div>
</div>
    <br>
    
    <div>
        <a v-for="item in Shop" :key="item.name">
            <button class="button" @click="show(item.name)">{{item.name}}</button>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="itemsArea" style="clear:both">
        <div class="itmems" v-if="face">
            <button v-on:click="setFaceDB('yXmkvJX/face1.png');" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/yXmkvJX/face1.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setFaceDB('JvfJb4K/face2.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/JvfJb4K/face2.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setFaceDB('nLMVbzP/face3.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/nLMVbzP/face3.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setFaceDB('YbXQLvz/face4.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/YbXQLvz/face4.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setFaceDB('SKDxwJh/face5.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/SKDxwJh/face5.png" class="item"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="itmems" v-if="mouth">
            <button v-on:click="setMouthDB('9gcDc7m/mouth1.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/9gcDc7m/mouth1.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setMouthDB('YydVm1m/mouth2.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/YydVm1m/mouth2.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setMouthDB('Kb6zD2k/mouth3.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/Kb6zD2k/mouth3.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setMouthDB('fFy4vzh/mouth4.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/fFy4vzh/mouth4.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setMouthDB('sggnv4Q/mouth5.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/sggnv4Q/mouth5.png" class="item"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="itmems" v-if="eye">
            <button v-on:click="setEyeDB('LJkLv0w/eye1.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/LJkLv0w/eye1.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setEyeDB('WfDLgLY/eye2.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/WfDLgLY/eye2.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setEyeDB('g3BDLhq/eye3.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/g3BDLhq/eye3.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setEyeDB('GCs470k/eye4.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/GCs470k/eye4.png" class="item"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="itmems" v-if="nose">
            <button v-on:click="setNoseDB('vwyfdZ7/nose1.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/vwyfdZ7/nose1.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setNoseDB('xG60wWw/nose2.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/xG60wWw/nose2.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setNoseDB('gZXdNx7/nose3.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/gZXdNx7/nose3.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setNoseDB('Dz702QP/nose4.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/Dz702QP/nose4.png" class="item"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="itmems" v-if="brow">
            <button v-on:click="setBrowDB('McjTk9b/brow1.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/McjTk9b/brow1.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setBrowDB('9YcwTF6/brow2.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/9YcwTF6/brow2.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setBrowDB('jzvXwND/brow3.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/jzvXwND/brow3.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setBrowDB('pRf0gkZ/brow4.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/pRf0gkZ/brow4.png" class="item"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="itmems" v-if="hair">
            <button v-on:click="setHairDB('XznYfkk/hair1.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/XznYfkk/hair1.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setHairDB('NYxMWNp/hair2.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/NYxMWNp/hair2.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setHairDB('qJrRKvg/hair4.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/qJrRKvg/hair4.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setHairDB('FJCZ966/hair5.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/FJCZ966/hair5.png" class="item"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="itmems" v-if="accessory">
            <button v-on:click="setAccDB('TLdd03X/acc1.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/TLdd03X/acc1.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setAccDB('RNVc1MN/acc2.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/RNVc1MN/acc2.png" class="item"></button>
            <button v-on:click="setAccDB('d6C3fhn/acc3.png')" class="avatarButton"><img src= "https://i.ibb.co/d6C3fhn/acc3.png" class="item"></button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
<!--   <a v-for="item in Shop" :key="item.id" >
        <a v-for="i in item.inventory" :key="i" >
            <img :src="`https://i.ibb.co/${i}`">
        </a>
            <br>  
    </a>
-->
  </div>

</template>

<script>
    import shop from "./shop.json";
    import json from "./dData.json";
    import db from "./firebaseInit";
    import firebase from "firebase";
    var auth= firebase.auth();
    //var userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
    //var exists = false;
  
    export default {
        name: "avatar",
        data: function() {
            return {
                isLoggedin: true,
                currentUser: true,
                Json: json,
                Shop: shop,
                face: true,
                eye: false,
                mouth: false,
                nose: false,
                brow: false,
                hair: false,
                accessory: false,
            };
        },
        /*
       name: "userAvatar",
        data() {
           return {
                nose: [
                        { id: ""},
                         {source: ""},
                         {layer: 25},
                ],
                 hair: [
                        { id: ""},
                         {source: ""},
                         {layer: 35},
                 ],
                acc: [
                        { id: ""},
                         {source: ""},
                         {layer: 40},
                ],
                eye: [
                         { id: ""},
                         {source: ""},
                         {layer: 15},
                        ],
                 brow: [
                         { id: ""},
                         {source: ""},
                         {layer: 30},
                 ],
                 face: [
                         { id: ""},
                         {source: ""},
                         {layer: 10},
                     ],
                      mouth: [
                         { id: ""},
                         {source: ""},
                         {layer: 20},
                        ]
                    } 
            },*/
       
        
        methods: {
           setNoseDB: function(noseID){
                var imgsrc =  noseID
                var userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
        
             db.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
            
                    nose: {
                         id: "4",
                         source: imgsrc,
                         layer: 25,
                        }
                    
                })
            },
            setHairDB: function(hairID){
                 var imgsrc =  hairID
                var userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
                db.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
                     
                    hair: {
                        id: "6",
                         source: imgsrc,
                         layer: 35,
                        }
                    
                })
            },
            setAccDB: function(accID){
                 var imgsrc =  accID
                var userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
                
                db.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
                    acc: {
                         id: "7",
                         source: imgsrc,
                         layer: 40,
                        }
                    
                })
            },
            setEyeDB: function(eyeID){
                 var imgsrc =  eyeID
                var userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
                db.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
                       eye: {
                         id: "2",
                         source: imgsrc,
                         layer: 15,
                        }
                    
                })
            },
            setBrowDB: function(browID){
                 var imgsrc =  browID
                var userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
                
                db.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
                   brow: {
                         id: "5",
                         source: imgsrc,
                         layer: 30,
                        }
                     
                })
            },
            setFaceDB: function(faceID){
                 var imgsrc =  faceID
                var userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
                
                db.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
                         face: {
                         id: "1",
                         source: imgsrc,
                         layer: 10,
                     }
                    
                })
            },
             setMouthDB: function(mouthID){
                 var imgsrc =  mouthID
                var userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
                
                db.collection('users').doc(userID).update({
                    mouth: {
                         id: "3",
                         source: imgsrc,
                         layer: 20,
                        }
                    
                })
            },
            show: function (part) {
                if(part=="face"){
                    this.face=true;
                    this.mouth = this.eye = this.nose = this.brow = this.hair = this.accessory = false;
                }
                else if(part=="mouth"){
                    this.mouth=true;
                    this.face = this.eye = this.nose = this.brow = this.hair = this.accessory = false;
                }
                else if(part=="eye"){
                    this.eye=true;
                    this.face = this.mouth = this.nose = this.brow = this.hair = this.accessory = false;
                }
                else if(part=="nose"){
                    this.nose=true;
                    this.face = this.eye = this.mouth = this.brow = this.hair = this.accessory = false;
                }
                else if(part=="brow"){
                    this.brow=true;
                    this.face = this.eye = this.nose = this.mouth = this.hair = this.accessory = false;
                }
                else if(part=="hair"){
                    this.hair=true;
                    this.face = this.eye = this.nose = this.brow = this.mouth = this.accessory = false;
                }
                else if(part=="accessory"){
                    this.accessory=true;
                    this.face = this.eye = this.nose = this.brow = this.hair = this.mouth = false;
                }
            },
        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
.item{
    border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width:250px;
}
.avatarBackground{
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 2px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 4px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 8px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 16px 8px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px 32px 16px;
    border-radius: 9%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 8px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 0px;
    height: 370px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #316ff5;
}
.itemsArea{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #698ad8;
    top: 9px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.button{
  padding: 9px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #316ff5;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  float: left;
  border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.avatarButton{
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56) 0px 22px 70px 4px;  
  padding: 9px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #316ff5;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  float: left;
  border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.avatarButton:hover{
    background-color: #6f94ec;
}
.avatarButton:active{
    background-color: #698ad8;
    transform: scaleY(1.02) scaleX(1.02);
}
.button:hover{
    background-color: #6f94ec;
}
.button:active{
    background-color: #698ad8;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
</style>
```

So, im trying to display parts of an avatar on a page. this works with dummy data of course, the json is being imported it works fine, and looks like:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "face", "layer": 10,  "source": "yXmkvJX/face1.png"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "eye", "layer": 15, "source": "GCs470k/eye4.png"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "mouth","layer": 20,  "source": "YydVm1m/mouth2.png"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "nose", "layer": 25, "source": "xG60wWw/nose2.png"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "brow", "layer": 30, "source": "McjTk9b/brow1.png"},
    {"id": 6, "name": "hair", "layer": 35, "source": "qJrRKvg/hair4.png"},
    {"id": 7, "name": "accessory", "layer": 40, "source": "d6C3fhn/acc3.png"}
]
```

this successfully grabs the links line by line and shows it in the first v-for for data in json. However, i want to store avatar components in a database, so I can output for each user. I can successfully save each component as its own array in the database. my issue comes when trying to read from this, im not sure exactly how to read it, as its not a json file, and the format is different than the dummy data used in the json file being imported. Another issue is trying to create a data type for each component, so when i pull from database, i can just set the data of the active avatar component to that of the database. The data i have commented out is where I have issues, when its active it messes up the whole page. Am i formatting it wrong? it shouldnt be messing with the active avatar being pulled from the json, but it is. it also messes up the item table which you can click buttons on to get each category of item.

Comment: your question is not super-clear, I would suggest to clarify, also reducing the amount of code example you gave us (it's a lot of code, it may be discouraging to try and read/interpret it).
If I understood correctly you want to save the available components (the "shop" object) in the firebase database. If so you would have to create e new collection (`db.collection('shop')`) and then load it into the `shop` data of the vue component inside the `mounted()` vue hook.

Comment: sorry, i realize that now lol. but i can set the data successfully in the database already, my issue comes where I need to essentially pull the data out, save to an object defined in the data , then output each one.

Comment: I'm no expert in firebase, but it should have a method like `getAll()` or `documents()` which will return all the documents (i.e. an array of objects) from the db. To load the data when the component/page is displayed for the first time just set the data inside the `mounted()` function.